# CSS hover width styles in different browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, browser, hover

My example is in this JSfiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/k9x4wmxk/3/

In Chrome browser, the hover CSS style (Line 71 in JSFiddle),

```
.photobox:hover img {width: 105%;}
```

present exactly what I want. The image width expands when hover.

**However in Firefox browser**, the above CSS style change the image height, not the width.

Does anyone know the problem? How can I fix it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code image hover

```
.photobox:hover img {    -moz-transform: scale(2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    -o-transform: scale(2);}
```

Comment: This works well. Thanks for reminding me this method :P